# How to create separate ToolBar for each activity in android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am developing an app where i need separate `Toolbar` for every activity, if i create separate toolbar then they collide/merge in some activity.
How to do it efficiently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in the activity add the given toolbar

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

To be precise Toolbar is just a view and you have to add it to your each Activity in which you want to show it.

Comment: I tried your technique but  got this erro :. This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: try adding this `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` also if u are using AppCompactActivity `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: it worked finally...Thanks

Comment: Hey i have added optionMenu but it is not aprear in my custom toolbar ?